# SQL and Visual Studios - Passing Variables

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need help with passing variables from my Visual Basic application into SQL queries to update my database and retrieve data depending on what variable I am using.

What is the correct way to do this :

My database is storing an appName, appLink and clickCount. Every time I click the associated app, it launches the link and then I would like it to increment the clickCount by one. to keep track of the most frequently used links.

I was thinking,

```
UPDATE myTable
SET clickCount = clickCount + 1
WHERE appName = (variable I am passing | link user clicked on)
```

but how do I get the variable from VB into my SQL statement? I am going to be doing numerous functions in my VB app and will need to openly pass data to and from my SQL server. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Side Note... When should I use stored procedures or functions in SQL rather than a function in VB?

Finally, the only language I really know is Python, so I am learning both SQL and VB to complete this project. In Python, using SQLite, the code is all in the same place. I can write one function that does all of the above. Can I do that in VB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't contains any actual code, so I will give you just a pseudocode.
First I define a method called UpdateClickCount that receives the application name and the linkname

```
 Public Sub UpdateClickCount(ByVal appName as String, ByVal linkName as String)
     Using sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
          sqlCon.Open()
          Dim sqlText = "UPDATE myTable SET clickCount = clickCount + 1 " & _
                        "WHERE appName = @name AND link = @link"
          Dim cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, sqlCon)
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", appName)
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", linkName)
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     End Using
 End Sub
```

Inside the method the first thing to do is open the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) using a connectionstring that contains all the information to reach the database.
Next the command text to update the database is defined and assigned to a string.
This command contains two parameters placeholders (@name and @link).
Now we can define the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with the string and the connection.
The last thing to do before executing the command, is to define the two parameters and their values.

The [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) submits everything to the database and your data is updated.
Generally this is the way to go for every command that update the database.

Comment: That is perfect! and answered my question :) When I have enough reputation points, I will come back and vote this up. Thank you for your time!

connectionString is my path to the .mdf correct ? Everything else makes perfect sense and I will be able to implement right away!

Comment: Not Always, connectionstrings could be in numerous format. A good reference point is this site http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: This is awesome... Makes even more sense after the edit. Thanks again and I hope you have a great weekend !

Comment: This answer demonstrates a *parametized query*, one of the two ways of doing this.  It's also worth mentioning the other way of doing this: *stored procedures*.

Comment: Ok Steve, gotta be honest. The connectionString has me confused. I have read through the links you provided, but I do not yet know enough about this language to make sense of it. I come from Python with way less rules and syntax... 
My .mdf is associated with the application already as in, I have data bindings pointed to it. It's in the same directory as the project files... Whats the easy answer here to be able to connect the two together? All of the reading I am doing is confusing me further :/

Comment: Usually you have two options. You open Sql Server Management Studio and attach, in a permanent way, your MDF file to the instance of SqlServer. This approach requires a connection string like this `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`, in the second option you distribute the MDF with your application and attach, at runtime, the file to an existing instance of SqlServer using this kind of connection `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;`. The subject is broad. A new question is in order

Comment: Ok, thank you. Let me try to look for existing questions / answers first so I don not duplicate, but it may come to that. I thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sqlcommand object to build your sql statement and use parameter placeholders to assign the varable.